# Difference between intervlan routing and policy based routing

Tags: networking, cisco, routing, switch, subnet

i try to use a Cisco C3550 24 EMI to split a single Hostaddress from a 26er subnet. My idea is, on one port i connect the cable to the 26er subnet (vlanWAN for example), on the second port i connect the firewall for most of the IPs (vlanLAN for example)  and now on the third Port i connect the single host i try to split (vlanCustomer1 for example).

By the way my idea is, to set allow/disallow for each IP in the subnet. So to Port 3 (vlanCustomer1) i allow only 1IP and the rest to port 2 (vlanLAN) and on Port1 (vlanWAN) i allow all IPs. Is that possible?

Any suggestion?

Regards
Rene

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sure sounds like you want some type of VACL setup.  Here is more info on Cisco's VACL capabilities:

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/switches/ps700/products_tech_note09186a008013565f.shtml

Although if you have EMI you could probably do this in simple ACLs as well.  Here is some more info on ACLs:

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/sw/secursw/ps1018/products_tech_note09186a00800a5b9a.shtml#intro